# Is it possible to query an integer in OData?

Tags: odata

I'm trying to query an integer field using Sitecore's OData ItemService.
This is my data:

```
"FieldValues": {
                "$count": 3,
                "SiteName": "SiteA",
                "Min": "101",
                "Max": "175"
            }
```

I used the following queries:

```
FieldValues/Min eq 101
FieldValues/Min lt 150
FieldValues/Min eq '101'
contains(FieldValues/Min,'1')
```

But neither of those return a result.

Comment: Try `$filter=/FieldValues/field operator 101?field=Min&operator=eq`. https://sitecoreodataitemserviceapi.docs.apiary.io/#reference/0/item-search-field-value/search-by-field-value

Comment: @x3mxray this threw an error `An identifier was expected at position 0`

Comment: I am looking solution for same thing. is it possible to query an integer field in Sitecore OData